# Persist String variable to Lob with Micronaut Data JDBC

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, micronaut, micronaut-data, lob

I'm using [Micronaut Data JDBC](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/latest/guide/#dbc) and I have an issue.

I have a `@MappedEntity` for JDBC with a `content` field that is a `String` used in a JPA context as follows:

```
@Lob
@Column(name = "content")
private String content;
```

I need to migrate this code to JDBC and I need that this `content` will be persisted as a Lob as well in a PostgreSQL.

With the current code, I'm just able to store the content as a `String`.

Any idea of how could I achieve that?

Comment: The default value for length of Colum is 255 chars. Try define `@Column(name="content" length="40000")` to exceed the capacity of a string.

Comment: Thanks @saw303 but didn't work. With small strings (less than the length set) it persists the data as String, not with an ID reference like it does when using JPA and @Lob. Note: length is an int `length="40000"`

Answer (score 0):

For persisting the `String` content as a LOB, what needs to be done is to annotate the field as follows:

```
@ColumnTransformer(write = "lo_from_bytea(0, ?::bytea)")
@Column(name = "content")
private String content;
```

by doing this, PostgreSQL stores an ID in the `content` column and the data is persisted in the `pg_largeobject` table as it was desired.